# requiring code fails to work no matter what I try

Tags: javascript, discord, eris

I'm attempting to break down my Discord bot into different files to keep everything neat. I've created a test file and tested it out, and it either fails to load or doesn't at all. Please let me know if there's anything I should add / fix.

required code:

```
module.exports.stupid = (bot) => {

bot.on('messageCreate', (msg) => {
    if (msg.content === 'yes'){
        bot.createMessage(msg.channel.id,'yes!!')
    }
});

}
```

How I'm requiring it:
`var cm1 = require('./staff.js')` -- I've tried const var & let

The require is placed after all of the npm libraries have been required.

Comment: "fails to work" is not something JavaScript says. What is the *exact* error you're getting?

Comment: I do not get an error, it just doesn't work.

Comment: what do you do next after requiring `./staff.js` ?

Comment: If you're just calling `require` then that code, which is a function, won't do anything unless you call it.

Comment: Even if I remove the var or anything, still fails to "load" the code.

Comment: This is some of the stuff that's after the require: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/717822384198910042/731226423615815691/unknown.png

Comment: It's always a good idea to include code within the question itself, not with attached screenshots.

Comment: Doesn't allow me to put the code in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the file `require_me.js` contains the following

```
module.exports.someMethod = () => {

}
```

And you require the file from `main.js`.

```
const myModule = require('./require_me.js');
```

You need to call your method after requiring a module.

```
myModule.someMethod();
```

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports